# Access inside folder with.htacces

Tags: angular, .htaccess, cpanel

My folder structure is like this: `www.testlink.com/angular/dist/my-app`.
I have to access this folder when  entering this link : `www.testlink.com/angular`.

How can I do with htaccess?

Comment: Please share your htacces file rules which you have written for solving this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use subdomain

htaccess configuration

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Add base url to index.html

```
<base href="http://subdomain.testlink.com/">
```

Configure apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.subdomain.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/of/your/directory

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for, a combination of an external redirection with an internal rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?angular/dist/my-app(/.*) /angular$1 [QSA,R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^/?angular(/.*) /angular/dist/my-app$1 [QSA,END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be enabled inside the http server for that and the interpretation of distributed configuration files (".htaccess") has to be enabled for that location inside the http server.

Comment: not working....

This is working....
`RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the ALPHA_USER cookie is set, serve the uncompressed files
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ALPHA_USER [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

# Rewrite everything
RewriteRule ^ dist/my-app/index.html [L]`

Comment: Sorry, but those are details specific to your setup you did not mention with any word in your question. So you hardly can expect anyone to consider those... The code I posted does what you asked for. If you actually are looking for something completely different, then certainly this answer will "not work for you".